# Combining strings and numbers in PHP for loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

PHP newbie here

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with the below syntax. I have a maximum of 4 files - $created_page1, $created_page2 each with a corresponding page title etc and would like to process these in a loop. However PHP throws a wobbly every time I try to concatenate the string and loop number - specifically $created_page.$num_pages doesn't result in sending $created_page1  or $created_page2 to the function, instead it just converts the string and number to an integer. Very basic I am sure but I would be very grateful for any help or a nicer solution that I can easily understand. Thanks in advance!

```
$addit_pages == 4;

for ($num_pages=1;$num_pages<=$addit_pages ;$num_pages++) { 

replaceFileContent   ($dir,$created_page.$num_pages,"*page_title*",$page_title.$num_pages); 
//replaceFileContent  ($dir,$created_page2,"*page_title*",$page_title2); 
//replaceFileContent  ($dir,$created_page1,"*page_title*",$page_title3); 
//replaceFileContent  ($dir,$created_page3,"*page_title*",$page_title4);    
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. what is `"*page_title*"`?

Comment: How far does it throw the wobbly?

Comment: and whats the content of these parameters ? i guess you are mixing up DATE and INTEGER or something like that !?

Comment: Please, learn to use arrays instead of numbered variables.

Comment: and thanks for this too deceze, if there's a more efficient way of doing this than thats the way i want to go, but one step at a time eh? am glad i know that this can be acheived better with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Your code to get the variable name should be:

```
${'created_page'.$num_pages}
```

This is because you have to evaluate the string inside the braces before you attempt to access the variable.

Your previous code was trying to access the variables $created_page and $num_pages, and simply concatenate their values into a string.

Of course, the same goes for the page_title variable

```
${'page_title'.$num_pages}
```

Comment: wow -so many responses so quickly. domvoyt I think you knew what I was getting at best, worked like a dream and i get it. but thanks to everyone- your answers are all helping me to get a grip on this thing.

Comment: No problem. @Aknosis had another approach that would work. Basically two different ways of using "Variable variables".

But as deceze said, much better done with arrays, so good luck with your learning :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
$addit_pages == 4;
```

for ($num_pages=1;$num_pages<=$addit_pages ;$num_pages++) {

replaceFileContent   ($dir,$created_page.strval($num_pages),"*page_title*",$page_title.strval($num_pages)); 
//replaceFileContent  ($dir,$created_page2,"*page_title*",$page_title2); 
//replaceFileContent  ($dir,$created_page1,"*page_title*",$page_title3); 
//replaceFileContent  ($dir,$created_page3,"*page_title*",$page_title4);
}

the PHP strval function makes any integer into a string

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is you want the variables `$created_page1; $created_page2, $created_page3` but php is probably throwing a notice that `$created_page` doesn't exist.

You need to use variable variables (is this what they're called?)

```
$addit_pages == 4;

for ($num_pages=1;$num_pages<=$addit_pages ;$num_pages++) { 
    $createdVar = 'created_page'.$num_pages;
    $titleVar = 'page_title'.$num_pages;
    replaceFileContent   ($dir,$$createdVar,"*page_title*",$$titleVar); 
}
```

When you use `$$` this first evaluates the variable `$createdVar` turns that into `created_page1` and then evaluates `created_page1` as if you had typed in `$created_page1`

Comment: Link for reference, "Variable variables" is the correct term it seems: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php